# Drawing lots in judaism

Tags: halacha

Sometimes, when I have an uncertainty or doubt, and I don't know what to choose or do, I throw a dice or flip a coin thinking that sort of randomness is in G-d's hand. I truly believe G-d does not play dice and everything that happens that's not in our control is what G-d wants.

I know *gorals* have been part of judaism throughout history. For example when the Cohen Gadol made a raffle to know where David was or in the story of Purim when Aman made a lot to choose a date to kill the jews.

Is it wrong to do this?

Comment: Feel free to edit. English is not my first language and I'm sure it's full of mistakes.

Comment: Arguably this is not a duplicate. There (at least based on the answer) it might be assumed that the question is where the outcome is assumed to be random, whereas here the questioner is clearly assuming that is not the case. (Which based on the ruling cited there, would implicitly suggest the opposite ruling...)